# Asp.net Selected Value Retain

Tags: asp.net

I want to save the user selected value in drop down after page refresh in asp.net page.

Give me the code that helps me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you have absolutely  no idea where to start? What have you tried, which tutorials have you read? Where did you get stuck? Do you have no code at all? What means "save" and "refresh"?

Comment: Please you give us some code. so that we can see what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

ASPX:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Label>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(string.Empty, string.Empty));
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("mehdi", "1"));
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("ali", "2"));
    }
}
```